# Tables of verbs conjugation

Tags: грамматика, обучение, глаголы

Is there a website (or a book) to find conjugation tables (at present, past, future, ...) of most common russian verbs (be, can, want, speak, do, learn, hear, ...) ?

Comment: https://goo.gl/f0Otzq

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, the very best verb conjugation site is http://rifmovnik.ru because it not only fully conjugates verbs, it also gives aspect pairs (or more), it shows the stress for all forms, it also shows noun and adjective declinations and has phonetic transcriptions throughout (optional - cyrillic-based).

All you have to do is enter an infinitive or any word, in any form, with any ending, and it will show you what headword it belongs to. So, for instance, if you enter the form **перевёл**, it will take you to the entry for **перевести**, with a link to **переводить**. You have to choose **словоформы** from the dropdown menu below the search field, otherwise you just get a list of words that rhyme with **перевёл**, since this is also a rhyming dictionary.

Similarly, if you come across the form **львы** and don't know what to make of it, just enter it in the search field, choose the option **словоформы** from the dropdown menu below, then click on **найти** and you will be taken to the entry for the noun **лев**, along with its full declension.

Comment: Noted! Thank you! You see, I need that site more than anyone :)

Comment: I saw that it's misspeled, but an engine of the site when I'm trying it, gave a hint to me with proposed lemmas and words. So I canceled my changes, I thought, "it was meant to be." ))

Comment: Sorry, what are you referring to?

Comment: to "лвы" on the [site](http://rifmovnik.ru/find). Just try it.

Comment: it doesn't know what to do with it because it's not a word. my mistake ;)

Comment: in the roll down list at search box try to choose the `словоформы` instead of `рифмы` and try again. Site's engine smart enough ))

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice site: [Russian Verb Conjugations](http://learningrussian.net/russian_verbs.php).

Answer (score 0):

An awesome site for verbs conjugation is [Wiktionary](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0).

Type is search:

"быть" — for verb "to be"

"мочь" — for verb "can"

"хотеть" — for verb "want"

"говорить" — for verb "to speak"

"делать" — for verb "to do"

"учиться" — for verbs "to learn" "to study" (in russian "to learn" and "to study" are equal in some senses, but not always)

"слышать" — for verb "to hear"

"смотреть" — for verb "to look"

"видеть" — for verb "to see"

"любить" — for verb "to love"

"идти" — for verb "to walk"

"бежать" — for verb "to run"

"лежать" — for verb "to lie" (The book lies on the table)

"врать" "лгать" — for verb "to lie" (When Pinocchio lies, his nose grows.)

"сидеть" — for verb "to sit"

"думать" — for verb "to think"

"прыгать" — for verbs "to jump" "to spring" "to leap" (in russian "to jump" "to spring" "to leap" are equal)

"кушать" "есть" — for verb "to eat"

"пить" — for verb "to drink"

"писать" — for verb "to write"

"читать" — for verb "to read"

"нравиться" — for verb "to like" (Он мне нра́вится. ― I like him)

"ненавидеть" — for verb "to hate"

Feel free to ask any other verbs (:

Comment: `in russian "to learn" and "to study" are equal` -  It would be an exaggeration to say `are equal`, please see [the explanation here](http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/8766/how-the-difference-between-to-study-and-to-learn-might-be-rendered-in-russia).

Comment: @Avtokod What I mean by equal is that in Russian there's no different words for one meaning sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

**ru wiktionary org** - most popular and easy
(sorry for links, i have no enough points to post a lot of links)

**gramota ru** - Russian for Russians) Here russians check russian words. Very hard)

Frequency dictionary:
http://www.artint.ru/projects/frqlist.php
here you can download **lemma al zip** it is text file with words that used more than 1 time per million.
You can convert it to Excel (replace spaces by ";") and open as CSV.

Or you can download converted:
http://file.qip.ru/file/XhZKX9_m/Russian_Frequency_Dictionary.html

So, try combo: Frequency Dictionary + Wiktionary

Answer (score 0):

Someone should mention it.
There is a kind of a standard dictionary:
[А. А. Зализняк, «Грамматический словарь русского языка»](https://ru.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%90._%D0%90._%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%B0)
(A Dictionary of Russian Grammar by [Zaliznyak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrey_Zaliznyak))
**[rifmovnik.ru](http://rifmovnik.ru/)** definitely has it as a base and is much more convenient to use.

Briefly: assumably a full formalised paradigm of the Russian conjugation and declension put in template tables and the system of labels. Every word in the Dictionary has such labels as a pointer to the necessary template(s) and to special notes needed to yield the resulting table of conjugation/declension for the word.
It is seemingly a basis of all on/off-line grammar tools and tables but in its 'raw' paper format this great dict can be a challenge and takes time to get an answer for a single word. Though for groups of words it can be of better help…